# error: use of undeclared identifier 'finalTotal'

Tags: c, while-loop

When I compile this simple code the output is the above error.

So how to declare `finalTotal` outside `while` loop?

```
while (total<endn)
{
    int finalTotal = (total + total/3 - total/4);
}

printf("no of years is %i\n", finalTotal)
```

NOTE:`total` and `endn` are part of the total code but not necessary for the question.

Comment: Your variable is only declared inside of the scope of your while loop. You try to access it from the `printf` which is outside the scope of where that local variable resides. You need to declare the `int finalTotal` before the while loop (in the parent scope). And then assign to it in the while-loop. And then the `printf` can access the variable since it is inside the same level of scope.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply move the declaration of finalTotal as an int to before the loop.

```c
int finalTotal = 0; // declare and initialize to 0 in case while loop does not run
while (total<endn)
{
    finalTotal = (total + total/3 - total/4);
}

printf("no of years is %i\n", finalTotal)
```

This does look like an infinite loop though, as neither total nor endn seems to change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on [scope](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm). Variables can only be accessed within their scope. Since you declare `int finalTotal` inside of the while loop, only other statements inside of the while loop can access it.

Instead you need to declare your variable in the outer scope, so that the following `printf` can access it.

For example:

```
int finalTotal;  // Declared outside of the while loop.
                 // You may want to consider initializing it
                 // with some value in case the while-loop
                 // never executes. (Such as -1 or something
                 // to signal an invalid number of years).

while (total<endn)  // NOTE: This may infinite loop. Perhaps a typo?
{
    // This scope has access to `finalTotal` since it was declared
    // by an outer scope.
    finalTotal = (total + total/3 - total/4);
}

// Now `finalTotal` can be accessed here, since it's within the same
// level of scope and not stuck inside the scope of the while-loop
// curly braces.
printf("no of years is %i\n", finalTotal)
```

As mentioned by others, another problem is that the `while` loop may never terminate since `total` and `endn` are not changing inside of the while loop. So it will potentially iterate forever.

Perhaps this was intended to be `while (finalTotal < endn)`.